# Remove the sample app, Android MDM?

Tags: android, mdm, administrator, device-admin

I was just doing some research on MDM. And found that Google provides some solution for it.

So I downloaded the sample app available on [SAMPLE MDM ANDROID](http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html)

I installed it on my phone. But I am not able to uninstall it.
How do I uninstall the app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just goto settting-> security -> Device Administrators -> uncheck your app then you can uninstall